# Are all $\mathbf{P}$ languages $\mathbf{P}$-complete with respect to polynomial-time reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

Question: Is language $L \in \mathbf{P}$ also $\mathbf{P}$-complete with respect to polynomial-time reduction?

My thoughts: Given a language $L \in \mathbf{P}$, we want to show that for any other language $L' \in \mathbf{P}: L' \leq_p L$. To do this, given any input $w' \in \Sigma^*$, we can check in polynomial time if $w' \in L'$. If:

- $w' \in L'$: construct a word $w \in L$.
- $w' \notin L'$: construct a word $w \notin L$.

This construction would satisfy the existence of $f\colon \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*, w' \in L' \iff f(w') \in L$.

This is where I stuck: Given a language $L$, how can we find a word $w \in L$ or a word $w \notin L$.

Addendum: I think I understood the problem. Since $L' \leq_p L$ only requires existence of $f\colon \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$, I don't need construct $f$.

Comment: I'd like to give you a hint: For any polynomials $p, q$, it holds true that $p + q$, $p\cdot q$, $p-q$ are also polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it right, here is what you are missing: if $L$ is not trivial (i.e, not empty and not $\Sigma^*$) then there are words $w_1\in L,w_2\notin L$. You can use them to construct $f$.

Comment: Actually, while one word w1 in L and one word w2 not in L are required to meet the definition of "P-complete", you can completely ignore that word (if L' is in P then you can prove that w' in L' or that w' is not in L' in polynomial time, without using w1 or w2 at all).

Comment: @gnasher729 thats correct, but for the syntax in the definiton of those reductions - this actually matters (since you cant find a word in $\emptyset$ so $L'$ reduces to $\emptyset$ $\iff L'=\emptyset$)